# Konjunktiv oder Indikativ nach "als ob"?

Tags: subjunctive, conjunction

In einem Grammatikbuch habe ich gelesen, dass „in der lässigen Umgangssprache“ nach der komparativen Konjunktion *als ob* der indikativische Modus stehen kann. Ich möchte die Muttersprachler fragen, ob Ihr tatsächlich den Indikativ in solchen Fällen bevorzugen würdet. Würdet Ihr in der gesprochenen Sprache tatsächlich sagen: „*Er tut so, als ob er einverstanden **ist***“ statt „*als ob er einverstanden **wäre***“?

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Im Moment zielt die Frage auf persönliche Meinungen/Vorlieben ab, und sollte daher als "opinion-based" geschlossen werden. Mir fällt auch leider nicht ein, wie man sie sinnvoll umformulieren kann, aber vielleicht hast Du ja eine Idee.

Comment: Es lassen sich mühelos Zeitungsbelege mit dem Indikativ finden.

Comment: Menschen, die sich auf GLSE rumtreiben, sprechen selbstverständlich nur gestochen scharfes und grammatikalisch korrektes, dialektfreies Hochdeutsch, formulieren präzise und geben sich mit sowas wie "Umgangssprache" gar nicht ab ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es ist an sich die ureigene Eigenschaft der Umgangssprache (in jeder Sprache), dass sie

- komplexe grammatische Formen wie z.B. den Konjunktiv,
- komplexe Tempera wie z.B. Futur II oder sogar Futur generell,
- komplexe Satzstellungen mit Nebensätzen
- komplexe Satzstrukturen

und generell alles, was an der Sprache etwas schwieriger ist, versucht zu vermeiden oder zu umgehen (also durch einfachere Konstrukte zu ersetzen), ohne aber dabei komplett unverständlich zu werden.

Muttersprachler, die sich in ihrer Freizeit bei Stackexchange mit ihrer Sprache beschäftigen, werden mit sehr großer Wahrscheinlichkeit ein wenig mehr Wert auf Korrektheit in der Sprache legen - Daher dürfte eine solche Frage *hier* (ausser, dass sie primär *opinion-based* ist) mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit keine statistisch verwendbare Antwort hervorrufen.